# Debounce "setting" of values in proxy trap without delay/timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, debouncing, es6-proxy

I try to understand how i can debounce a "set" trap in javascript proxy.

```js
function debounce(func, wait, immediate = false) {
  let timeout = null;

  return function(...args) {
    let later = () => {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) {
        func.apply(this, args);
      }
    };

    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);

    if (immediate && !timeout) {
      func.apply(this, args);
    }
  };
}

const data = {
  p1: false,
  p2: true,
  p3: false,
  p4: true
};

const caller = debounce(() => {
  console.log("data object updated", data);
}, 100);

// catch setting of values
const obj = new Proxy(data, {
  set(target, prop, value, receiver) {

    // how to debounce this
    // with debounce i mean:
    // waiting for all properties to be set
    // this does not mean that all props are set
    // e.g. just 2 of the 4 props could be set

    // feedback
    console.log(`Set ${prop}=${value}`);

    caller();

    // handle the setting stuff
    return Reflect.set(target, prop, value, receiver);
  }
});

// happens asynchron somwhere else in the code
// set all props to new value
Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
  obj[key] = false;
});

setTimeout(() => {
  // simluate setting of not all props
  Object.keys(obj).slice(1, 3).forEach((key) => {
    obj[key] = true;
  });
}, 1000);
```

The problem is, not all properties are set, which means you can't rely on the number of properties/keys to wait for. E.g. Sometimes are just 2 set, sometimes the whole object is set to new values/updated.

How can i debounce the setting without a delay?

Is there somehow a "operation" that tells me that all object keys are setted to new values?
Dont know how exactly to phrase this.

I simple want to debounce the set trap, and wait for all values to be setted before executing something else.

Comment: You need some way for the updater to signal when it has started and when it's done. Then the other code can ignore the intermediate states while the updates are in progress.

Comment: You can use a flag variable. Set `updateInProgress = true` when you start updating, `updateInProgress = false` when it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there somehow a "operation" that tells me that all object keys are setted to new values?

No, there is no such thing. Code just goes on the execute, it does not know (or even keep track of) when it is "done". You just have a sequence of property assignments. Grouping them into subsequences that are "complete" before something else happens is totally arbitrary.

Your code with the delay appears to work just fine. You can make the delay shorter arbitrarily, use `setTimeout(…, 0)` or also a microtask (with [`queueMicrotask(…)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/queueMicrotask)) instead:

```
function debounce(func) {
    let active = false;
    const later = () => {
        active = false;
        func();
    };
    return () => {
        if (active) return;
        active = true;
        queueMicrotask(later);
    };
}
```

Comment: tbh: i have thought about something like `queueMicrotask()` but i couldnt put it together. How would a solution with it look like?

Comment: I just tried it with 0 delay, and it works... I never thought about setting delay to `0`. But it would be realy awesome if you could provide a solution with `queueMicrotask()` for me to learn something new.

Comment: @Marc Since there's not `clearMicrotask`, you have to check whether the task has already been scheduled and avoid re-scheduling it, instead of always clearing and (re)scheduling it. But conceptionally it's just the same. `function debounce(func) { let active = false; const later = () => { active = false; func(); }; return () => { if (active) return; active = true; queueMicrotask(later); }; }`

Comment: Thank so much. Never worked with `queueMicrotask()`, but makes sense to me now how it could be used. If you want to updated your answer, i would accept it.

Comment: @Marc Updated. But really it shouldn't make much of a difference to you whether you use `setTimeout` or `queueMicrotask`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. If possible, i want to learn something new/of my mistakes. Because i never used `queueMicrotask`, im interested in how a solution with it would look like.